# What typeface is used by MacOS to render unicode glyphs?

Tags: typography, web-fonts, mac

What font is being used in the following screenshot (on a latest MacOS/Safari) to render the unicode glyphs?

[image]

The screenshot is taken from the page http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html

Is this font available somewhere publicly as an SVG?

Comment: Hi gen and welcome to GDSE! Your font id question is on topic here, but I will edit out the last question; it should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: It'll also bump your question up the homepage so you'll be more likely to get an answer

Comment: You requested this question to be migrated to [apple.se]. As it is on-topic here, I would not do this. However, given that you have received no answer here in a week, this is a case where it is commonly accepted that you cross-post the same question on a different suitable site (like [apple.se]). If you do this, please link the questions to each other.

Answer (score -1):

To render the Unicode glyphs, the font "Wingdings" is used, according to my Chrome extension "WhatFont".

You can download the SVG files from here - https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wingdings.svg
Direct link - https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Wingdings.svg

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you have a look at the screenshot in my original post and the Wingdings.svg you linked you'll see that the font being used on my macOS/Safari setup is not Wingdings...